# Button in dialog box won't Post back

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, post, webforms

I have a dialog box which I'm displaying with the jQuery `.dialog()` function, and this dialog box contains a button which I want to post back to another page, but it's not working. I can't get it to post with the `PostBackUrl` attribute set, or with the `OnClick` (this never fires). However, when I click one of the `Calendar` dates, which I suppose cause a post back by default, the page posts back to the url I set in the buttons `PostBackUrl` attribute! I want to use the `asp:Calendar`, but disable the default post back behavior on selection, and have posting occur only when the user selects the button, but still obviously have the selected date of the `Calendar` available on post back. Here's the `.aspx` file...

```
<form id="form1" runat="server">
        <asp:Button ID="btnShowDialog" runat="server" Text="Click to Show Dialog" OnClientClick="showDialog(); return false;" />
        <div class="divDialog" style="display: none">
            <table style="width: 100%;">
                <tr>
                    <td>First Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtFirstName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox></td>
                    <td>Last Name: <asp:TextBox ID="txtLastName" runat="server" Text=""></asp:TextBox></td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        How Old are You?
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlAge" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        How Many Siblings do You Have?
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="ddlNumberSiblings" runat="server">
                            <asp:ListItem Value="1">1</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="2">2</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="3">3</asp:ListItem>
                            <asp:ListItem Value="4">4</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Calendar ID="calBirthday" runat="server" Width="200" >
                            <DayStyle BackColor="Yellow"  />
                        </asp:Calendar>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <asp:Button ID="btnSubmit" runat="server" Text="Submit" />
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>
    </form>
```

...and the jQuery script...

```
   <script>
        function showDialog() {
            $('.divDialog').dialog({ modal: true, show: 'slide', title: 'Please Enter Information Below', width: 500 });
        }
    </script>
```

...and here is how the asp:Button and a date in the asp:Calendar are rendered in the browser....

```
<a title="April 28" style="color:Black" href="javascript:__doPostBack('calBirthday','4866')">28</a>
```

....

```
<input id="btnSubmit" type="submit" onclick="javascript:WebForm_DoPostBackWithOptions(new WebForm_PostBackOptions("btnSubmit", "", false, "", "Profile.aspx", false, false))" value="Submit" name="btnSubmit">
```

EDIT: The button submission doesn't work, regardless of whether I include the asp:Calendar control or not. But Calendar control selection submission works for some reason.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem with this kind of dialogs is that they move what you give them as content somewhere outside the form.

Take that example: http://jsfiddle.net/Qej8S/1/

I have place the content inside the `keeper`

```
<div class="keeper">
    <div class="divDialog" style="display: none">
    The content of the dialog        
    </div>
</div>
```

but if run it, you see that (ether the colors, ether with the dom utilities of the browser) the dialog is moving the content outside of the keeper, and in your case is move it outside the `form` and thats why is not fires up.

For solution I came up with some kind of a hack. After the dialog is created move it back to the form. Here is an example. I place a div with a specific id, inside the form as:

`<div id="MoveItHere"></div>`

and I set the move right after the dialog is created as:

```
$('.divDialog').dialog({modal: true, show: 'slide', title: 'Please Enter Information Below', width: 200, 
create: function( event, ui ) 
 {
    // this is the trick, I move it again inside the form, on a specific place.
    $("#MoveItHere").html($(this).parent());
 }
});
```

And here is the online test, that is working if you see the dom: http://jsfiddle.net/Qej8S/2/

Comment: Ah, I see you're right. I suppose I can just treat the entire form as I was treating div.divDialog in the javascript function, right?

Comment: @MassStrike I know the issue, but I do not have a suggestion for the moment. I am looking for...

Comment: @MassStrike I have update my answer with a solution, check it out. Maybe is need some tweaks, if you open many times the dialog, if the div stay there, and some other, but its work as it is.

Comment: @MassStrike Also see this parametre http://api.jqueryui.com/dialog/#option-appendTo  its seems that do what I try, but I test it and did not work to me. Maybe work to you.

Comment: Awesome Aristos, I really appreciate it! I'm going to check it out now!

Comment: hmm, still not working for me for some reason...seems like it should work perfectly...

Comment: Ok, got it. It worked for me like this...
function showDialog() {
            $('.divDialog').dialog({
                modal: true, show: 'slide', title: 'Please Enter Information Below', width: 500,
                focus: function (event, ui) {
                    $('.divInnerForm').append($(this));
                }
            });
        }