# Clicking the button it select all my page (working on browser not on mobile)

Tags: vb.net, jquery-mobile, webforms

First of all, I am 2 days old using jquery mobile, the work I done is mostly by trial and error and reading.

I have added aspx button and enhance it with jquery, it looks fine except 2 behavior

1- When I assign an icon to the button, i tried to click it in browser, but the code I write in the btn_search_Click does not fire, after many checking and and testing I notice that code will fire if I clicked the icon "search image" itself.

2- When I tried the button on my mobile "Galaxy Note" it seem the whole page I write is getting selected by light orange as in the image below, later on I discovered that pressing the button give this effect, but pressing the "search icon on the button" works well

Is that normal behavior?

https://plus.google.com/u/0/115817137660799291682/posts/7tN5kXdFobt

here is html/jquery the page (without the table for movies)

```
<%@ Page Language="VB" AutoEventWireup="false" CodeFile="Default2.aspx.vb" Inherits="Default2" %>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>jQuery Mobile Demos</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/themes/default/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="_assets/css/jqm-demos.css">
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans:300,400,700">
    <script src="js/jquery.js"></script>
    <script src="_assets/js/index.js"></script>
    <script src="js/jquery.mobile-1.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <style type="text/css">
        .auto-style1
        {
            width: 61px;
        }
        .auto-style2
        {
            width: 540px;
        }
        .style1
        {
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <table style="width: 92%;">
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                Num:
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_num" runat="server" type="search"></asp:TextBox>
                <td class="style1">
                    <asp:Button ID="btn_search" runat="server" Text="Search" Width="31%" data-inline="true"
                        data-theme="b" data-icon="search" data-iconpos="left" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                Name:
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                <asp:TextBox ID="txt_name" runat="server" type="text"></asp:TextBox>
            </td>
            <td>
                <asp:Button ID="btn_balance" runat="server" Text="Get Balance" Width="31%" data-inline="true"
                    data-theme="b" data-icon="grid" data-iconpos="left" />
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td class="auto-style1">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td class="auto-style2">
                &nbsp;
            </td>
            <td>
                &nbsp;</tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

> but the code I write in the btn_search_Click does not fire

This is probably happens because the jQuery mobile toolkit is usually moves the content outside the asp.net `form` and when you click on the button the form is not fires. Also there is the other case that load it with ajax in a dialog, this also can not work as it is.

> I notice that code will fire if I clicked the icon "search image"
>   itself.

The icons buttons usually are handle the post back with javascript, and that why this work, because is call the post - however probably you do not send the correct data if the rest page have been change places.

Here is a similar answer: [Button in dialog box won't Post back](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16430389/button-in-dialog-box-wont-post-back/16430456#16430456)

I have diagnose the issue, but did not have a general solution to give.

Comment: When I remove Width="31%" the not working button works well. Is that could be a reason of what you called "move the content outside the asp.net form" or Width="31%" reduce the button area to where it should accept the click?

Comment: @SamirIbrahim This is sounds very weird - I really do not know.

Comment: I agree with you on "weird". I had to be at work to test the modification on my phone to see if that light orange color will go away if I remove **Width="31%"**

Answer (score 0):

Here is the result of my testing telling only the behavior I saw not why it happens since I don't know :)

**width="31%"** has that effect on both computer browser and mobile browser, it seems it shrink the area where the button should be clicked (tested)

I include **width="31%"** trying to reduce the width of button since I put the button in table row "I want the button to occupy 31% of the column width , but later I discovered that I can use **data-inline="true"** nice discovery :)

After I removed the **width="31%"** and try it on my default mobile browser, the page being selected by light orange color is gone, but only the button itself is covered by the orange color "I guess that is normal"

When I tried the page on Opera mobile browser the color selecting the button became light blue "I guess every browser has his own behavior.

When I tried the page on Opera mobile browser using button with **width="31%"**. Pressing the button was not having the light orange color, but the button cannot be pressed except in a specific area "first 31% of the button width". So every mobile browser can behave differentially using jquery/asp page.

My problem is solved by removing the tag **width="31%"**

Thanks Aristos and every one.

Comment: should I mark my own response as answer or an admin will do it?